# css - table cells incorrectly aligned to header cells when global table { display:table-cell } was used

Tags: jqgrid

I had the global table's css set so non-related jqGrid table cells render correctly in all web browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.).

```
table { display: table-cell; }
```

A few years later, I start using jqGrid for 1st time and noticed the table cells rendered fine in IE but not in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

So, what css property should I inject into to the ui.jqgrid.css file for the jqGrid to render properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your problem correctly. I suppose that you *have to* have the CSS

```css
table { display: table-cell; }
```

because of some reason and you want do display jqGrid correctly. In the case you can just add CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid table { display: table; }
```

which override the "global" setting for all tables used by jqGrid.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/fletchsod.htm) which uses the styles and which displays the grid correctly.

Comment: Oh wow!!  It works great now.  Yea, specifying property on jqgrid to override the website's global setting is what I'm looking for.  you got that right.  Thanks man!

Comment: one last request.  how do i vertically-align: middle the jagrid column header (<th></th>)??   thaznks...

Comment: @fletchsod: The problem of asking questions *in comments* is the following: nobody else will find the information by searching on stackoverflow. So please ask better new question instead of doing it in the comment.